# Google Maps doesn't fully load in my mobile app

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've included a google maps geolocation in a mobile app I am developing. The map doesn't fully load / fit the screen in the ripple mobile emulator although works successfully in chrome. My css is set to 100% for height and width.

I have a splash screen before the map canvas which loads the geolocation. When the code for the splash is removed, the issue is gone. I thought I would include the splash screen code in case is it actually conflicting with the map canvas.

I initially thought that is was the amount of code which I had placed in one page although when I trim it down to the following code, the issue is still present.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>

<script> 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    setTimeout(hideSplash, 3000);
    });

    function hideSplash() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#map-page", "fade");
    }
});
</script>

<script>
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
    function success(pos) {
        // Location found, show map with these coordinates
        drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    }
    function fail(error) {

    }
    // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
} else {
    drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map
}

function drawMap(latlng) {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center); 
    });
    }
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Splash Screen -->  
<div data-role="page" id="splash"> 
    <div id="verycentre">
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Map Page -->   
<div data-role="page" id="map-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>
        <a href="#preferences" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a> 
        <a href="#defaultpanel" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a>
        </h1>
    </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="map-canvas">
        <!-- Map Canvas --> 
        </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not used the initialize() function that constructs the Map object on window load to ensure that the map is placed on the page after the page is fully loaded.

With this in place I then used the the jQuery mobile transition event:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#map-page",function(){
    $(window).ready(function() { initialize(); });
});
```

Therefore I initialise the google map **after** the splash screen code rather than at the same time which was causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> resize - Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div
>   changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').

Because you show a splash screen before you show the map, your map container is hidden so when the map is rendered you have to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` after showing the modal.

The fact that removing the splash screen fixes the problem, is because the map container is not hidden when you render the map.

Comment: Apologies for the greatly delayed response. So where in the code should I call the google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') ? I'm experimenting at the moment but with no success.

Comment: You could try it in hideSplash

Comment: Hmmm no luck I'm afraid. I'll keep probing, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common problem in JQM.

Although you have got the solution I would like to give some more details about this .

**Cause of the problem**

The JQM uses script to layer divs over your normal div to make it more enrich and look better
So when you initialize the `google map` these hidden layer causes the problem to show it completely

Most of the time as I have researched in **Google** that the map is shown in the upper left corner of the window :).

**Easy fix**
This one goes only for JQM pages

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map", function() {



});
```

Just put your google map code inside the above code what it does is that the map will load only after all the `divs` have been loaded . Please see the event [`pageshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) in JQM website.

Just change the `#map` selector to the id of the page where the map has to be loaded .

Hope I have helped you or others who have been facing the same problem :)

Thanks & Regards